# Grails testcase fails

Tags: grails, groovy, junit, grails-2.0

i have a domain class like

```
package trip.side
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

class HotelStay {
    String hotel
    Date checkIn
    Date checkOut

    static constraints = {
    }
    String toString(){
     def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE")
    "${hotel}(${sdf.format(checkIn)} to ${sdf.format(checkOut)})"
    }

}
```

and wrote a test case toString Method inside HotelStayTests

```
void testToString() {
      def h = new HotelStay(hotel:"Hilton")
      def df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
      h.checkIn = df.parse("10/1/2008")
      h.checkOut = df.parse("10/5/2008")
      println h
      assertToString h, "Hilton (Wednesday to Sunday)"
    }
```

complete HotelStayTests  Class

```
package trip.side



import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(HotelStay)
class HotelStayTests {

   void testSomething() {
   // Simple test by creating new object and asserting it
          // fail "Implement me"
        HotelStay hs = new HotelStay(hotel:"Ibis")
        assertEquals "Ibis", hs.hotel
    }   

    void testToString() {
      def h = new HotelStay(hotel:"Hilton")
      def df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
      h.checkIn = df.parse("10/1/2008")
      h.checkOut = df.parse("10/5/2008")
      println h
      assertToString h, "Hilton (Wednesday to Sunday)"
    }
}
```

but which fails and giving the error report

```
No signature of method: trip.side.HotelStayTests.assertToString() is applicable for argument types: (trip.side.HotelStay, java.lang.String) values: [Hilton(Wednesday to Sunday), Hilton (Wednesday to Sunday)] Possible solutions: testToString()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: trip.side.HotelStayTests.assertToString() is applicable for argument types: (trip.side.HotelStay, java.lang.String) values: [Hilton(Wednesday to Sunday), Hilton (Wednesday to Sunday)]
Possible solutions: testToString()
    at trip.side.HotelStayTests.testToString(HotelStayTests.groovy:28)
System output
Hilton(Wednesday to Sunday)
```

any idea what going wrong here?

Comment: Does your test class extend `GroovyTestCase`?

Comment: @tim_yates: no .. i have edited my question

Comment: `assertToString` is part of `GroovyTestCase`...  Have you tried putting `extends GroovyTestCase` in your class definition?

Comment: Did not work in what way?  Same exception?

Comment: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: toString() on value: Hilton(Wednesday to Sunday) expected:<Hilton (Wednesday to Sunday)> but was:<Hilton(Wednesday to Sunday)>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: toString() on value: Hilton(Wednesday to Sunday) expected:<Hilton (Wednesday to Sunday)> but was:<Hilton(Wednesday to Sunday)>
 at trip.side.HotelStayTests.testToString(HotelStayTests.groovy:28)
System output

Hilton(Wednesday to Sunday)

Comment: That's working...  You're expecting a space between `Hilton` and `(`, but in your `toString` method, there is no space...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assertToString` is part of [the GroovyTestCase class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/GroovyTestCase.html).

Your test class needs to `extend GroovyTestCase` to gain this functionality

Comment: What if i do not extend GroovyTestCase(as in grails 2.0) and want to achieve same functionality? i mean what is the alternative to assertToString ?

Comment: You could do: `assert h?.toString() == 'Hilton (Wednesday to Sunday)'`